# Calculating albedo values with landsat 7 ImageCollection/FeatureCollection error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: remote-sensing, google-earth-engine, function, landsat-7

I am facing a technical difficulty with Google Earth Engine

I am trying to retrieve the albedo value of the state of Idaho by using Landsat7 TOA reflectance imagery over the span of a year. ('2005-01-01','2005-12-31').

The equation to retrieve the albedo is known as:

```js
var albedo = ((0.356*blue)+(0.130*red)+(0.373*nir)+(0.085*swir)+
(0.072*swir2)- 0.018)/ (1.016);
```

Here is the whole code that I have so far:

```js
var region = table;
var col05 = donnee.filterBounds(region).filterDate('2005-01-01', '2005-12-31');
var calc_albedo = function(donnee){
  var red = donnee.select('B3');
  var blue = donnee.select('B1');
  var nir = donnee.select('B4');
  var swir = donnee.select('B5');
  var swir2 = donnee.select('B7');
  var albedo = ((0.356*blue)+(0.130*red)+(0.373*nir)+(0.085*swir)+(0.072*swir2)- 0.018)/ (1.016);
  return albedo
}
var albedo_2005 = col05.map(calc_albedo);
var clipped05 = albedo_2005.median().clip(region);
strong textMap.addLayer(clipped05,{min: 0.0, max: 1},'albedo_2005');
```

var region = table is a shapefile of the Idaho state I have upload via the tool google provides.
var donnee is the ImageCollection "USGS Landsat 7 TOA Reflectance (Orthorectified)"

Finally, the error I am receiving is :

> albedo_2005: Layer error: reduce.median, argument 'collection':
>   Invalid type. Expected: ImageCollection. Actual: FeatureCollection.

Comment: What happens if you cast the feature to an image, e.g. as `return ee.Image(albedo)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do math that way (using javascript math operators) due to client/server issues.  To do something similar, you need to use image.expression:

```
var albedo = donnee.expression(
  "((0.356*blue)+(0.130*red)+(0.373*nir)+(0.085*swir)+(0.072*swir2)- 0.018)/ 1.016",
  {
    red: donnee.select('B3'),
    blue: donnee.select('B1'),
    nir: donnee.select('B4'),
    swir: donnee.select('B5'),
    swir2: donnee.select('B7')
  })
```